# Near vs nearby vs nearly

Tags: grammar

I am always confused with these 3 items because sometimes they are confusing. Near is preposition, adjective, and adverb altogether. on other hand nearly and nearby are only used as adverb.

Would someone  tell me the proper use of these items with proper examples in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

"That was a near miss!"

"The shop is nearby"

"Are we nearly there yet?"